# Isomorphism of $\Bbb C[x]$ and $x\cdot\Bbb C[x]$ as modules over $\Bbb C[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R = \mathbb{C}[x]$. Are $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $x \cdot \mathbb{C}[x]$ isomorphic as $R$ modules? I was thinking of the map $f(x) \mapsto x f(x)$ as a potential isomorphism. It is certainly a bijection, and it seems to satisfy the axioms for a module homomorphism.

Comment: If uncertain prove it from the definition: If $F(f)(x)=xf(x)$ and $a,b,f,g\in R$, then $F(af+bg)(x)=xa(x)f(x)+xb(x)g(x)=a(x)F(f)(x)+b(x)F(g)(x)=[aF(f)+bF(g)](x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggested map is, indeed, an isomorphism of $R$-modules. To be precise, define $$\varphi\colon\Bbb C[x]\to x\cdot\Bbb C[x], f\mapsto x\cdot f$$
First off, check that it is a bijection

- Injectivity: Suppose $\varphi(f)=\varphi(g)$, then 
  $$\varphi(f)=\varphi(g)\iff x\cdot f=x\cdot g\iff x\cdot(f-g)=0\iff f=g$$
- Surjectivity: Let $\tilde f\in x\cdot\Bbb C[x]$. Then $\tilde f=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx^k$, where $a_k\in\Bbb C$. Let $f:=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k+1}x^k$. Certainly
  $$\varphi(f)=x\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k+1}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k+1}x^{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^na_kx^k=\tilde f$$

So $\varphi$ defines a bijection between $\Bbb C[x]$ and $x\cdot\Bbb C[x]$. It remains to show that $\varphi$ satisfies the axioms of a $R$-module homomorphism. As a straightforward computation shows we have for $a,b\in R$ and $f,g\in\Bbb C[x]$
\begin{align*}
\varphi(a\cdot f+b\cdot g)&=x\cdot(a\cdot f+b\cdot g)\\
&=x\cdot(a\cdot f)+x\cdot(b\cdot g)\\
&=(x\cdot a)\cdot f+(x\cdot b)\cdot g\\
&=(a\cdot x)\cdot f+(b\cdot x)\cdot g\\
&=a\cdot(x\cdot f)+b\cdot(x\cdot g)=a\cdot\varphi(f)+b\cdot\varphi(g)
\end{align*}
Therefore $\Bbb C[x]$ and $x\cdot\Bbb C[x]$ are isomorphic as $R$-modules and an isomorphisms given by $\varphi$.

Comment: And the same proof shows $R$ and $xR$ are isomorphic as $R$-modules if $R$ is a commutative ring, for any non-zero divisor $x \in R$.  (Note that you don't really need to say anything for surjectivity: $\varphi(R) = xR$ by definition.)

Comment: @JairTaylor For one reason or another the surjectivity part wasn't immediately clear to me; so I dediced to include it (and, of coure, so that the answer is complete). I was working under the implicit assumption of $R$ being an integral domain (as the given ring $R$ is indeed one). However, nice to see how far this generalizes.